# Merge filesystem and filesystems

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filesystem) and [filesystems](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filesystems) should be merged, 135 on [filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filesystem) and 565 on [filesystems](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filesystems) .  I guess keep [filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filesystem) to prefer the singular, but I don't feel strongly.

Comment: They'll just syn one to the other, so people can type in whatever they want and it'll all end up in the same pile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. I also merged in [file-system](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/file-system) as well since it was lurking in the corners hoping I wouldn't notice it.

Also, I'm 90% sure this is that one tag-set I saw, said I'd get to it later, and promptly forgot the details of. Kudos for finding it.